# Multiple Software Timers

Tags: c

I've been using the following method for implementing a software timer in code:

```
typedef enum TIMER_CONFIG
{
    ENABLE_TIMER,
    DISABLE_TIMER,
} TIMER_CONFIG;

struct timer_module{
    uint32_t count;
    uint32_t start_count;
    unsigned int enable;
};

struct timer_module timer_1;
struct timer_module timer_2;

void tc_ms_tick(struct tc_module *const module_inst)
{
    ms_count++;     
}

volatile uint32_t get_ms_count(void){
    return(ms_count);
}

void checkTimers(void){

    if (timerIsDone(&timer_1)){
        timerConfig(&timer_1, DISABLE_TIMER,0);
        // Do something
    }

    if (timerIsDone(&timer_2)){
        timerConfig(&timer_2, DISABLE_TIMER,0);
        // Do something
    }
}

void timerConfig(struct timer_module *timer, TIMER_CONFIG timer_config, uint32_t timer_time){

    switch (timer_config)
    {
        case ENABLE_TIMER:
            timer->enable = 1;
            timer->start_count = get_ms_count();
            timer->count = timer_time;
            break;
        case DISABLE_TIMER:
            timer->enable = 0;
            break;
        default:
            //Do Nothing
            break;
    }
}

bool timerIsDone(struct timer_module *timer)
{
    bool timer_status = false;

    if (timer->enable){
        if(((get_ms_count() - timer->start_count) >= timer->count)){
            timer_status = true;
        }
    }

    return timer_status;
}

// Main loop    
int main(void)
{       
    // Set the timer for 5 seconds
    timerConfig(&timer_1, ENABLE_TIMER, 5000);

    while (1) {
        checkTimers();      // Check background timers
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This implementation works well for the majority of cases, however it doesn't scale well. I've heard of using linked lists for something like this but I'm fairly new to C and I couldn't find an example that I understood. Any help is appreciated!

Kyle

Comment: Might be easiest to just make an array of timers and then loop over them. A linked list isn't worth the effort when you can just re-use timers.

Comment: what's your question? You're just telling us stuff

Comment: The suggestion to use linked lists assumes that you're making a priority queue. The advantage of a priority queue is that you only need to check the first item. All the other items in the queue will either need servicing at the same time or after the first item.

Comment: It seems like your trying to implement a portion of a small round robin kernel that is driven off time counts. Depending on how many timers involved, an array is probably good enough. If you trying to make the code generic, then a caller supplied node structure that includes a next pointer could be used with a linked list, using a static (global) head pointer for the timer. You'd also need to consider if you want the ability to remove a node structure from the list when the software timer is no longer needed.

Comment: Well, when you have a lot of timers with long intervals compared to the time taken to check the timer, it's common to keep them in a container struct sorted by expiry-time.  This means that the  thread that checks timers usually only needs to time out the timer at the head of the list, no matter how many timers are in there, and could use a CPU-cycle-efficient kernel sleep/wait to do so.  A linked-list MAY be appropriate for such a timer-container.   In your example code, it does not really mattter since you are doing nothing else but check timers in your one thread with no kernel sleep/wait.

Comment: Assume get_ms_count() returns an uint8 for simplicity. 
Scenario: get_ms_count() returns 253 and this value gets loaded into timer->start_count. What would happen now if a 5 sec timer is intended? There would be a roll over after 255 right